# How Can I Merge Multiple Files with Unequal Rows in R

Tags: r, csv, merge, export-to-csv

I have about 100 text files with two columns and about 320-500 rows I would like to merge into a single .csv file.

For example, I have file A that looks like this

**A B** 

1 100 

2 200 

3 300 

4 400 

 

 
and File B looks like this

**A B** 

1 100 

2 200 

3 300 

4 400 

5 300 

6 400

However, when I enter this code into R: `write.csv (data_list, ("file.csv"), row.names = FALSE, na="")`, 
 I get this error message: `"Error in data.frame(list(V1 = c(0.025, 0.035, 0.045, 0.055, 0.065, 0.075, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 500, 599, 508, 489, 547, 624, 587, 534, 499, 494, 566, 520, 541, 543, 615"`

I want my files to look like this (a file that combines all 100 text files of mine by the two columns):

File AB

**A B** 

1 100 

2 200 

3 300 

4 400 

1 100 

2 200 

3 300 

4 400 

5 300 

6 400 

in one jumbo csv file. Please help me if this is possible. I'm new to scripting and will provide more info as necessary.

Comment: So have you read the data into R? Because your code uses `write.csv`. Is `data_list` a list of data.frames? Do you want to combine that into a larger data.frame first? Have you looked at `rbind_list` from `dplyr`? That should make that easier (since you're really just "binding" rather than "merging")

Comment: Yes, I have. `data_list` is all of the files that I want to use to create the csv file.  I just tried `rbind_list` and it worked to bind the names of the files but I would like to bind the contents of all of those files. Sorry, I'm not sure if I'm explaining correctly!

Comment: Can you show the code you used?  If `A, B` are the objects, `bind_rows(A,B)` gets the result as you showed.

Comment: Of course!  `setwd("/directory")

datafiles <-list.files (pattern='*.file.txt')
data_list = lapply (datafiles, read.table, header=FALSE)

write.csv (data_list, ("/directory/file.csv"), row.names = FALSE, na="")`

Comment: What is the result of  `bind_rows(data_list)`? (assuming that you using the new dplyr version).  BTW, you are using `write.csv` on a list.

Comment: I got this `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "bind_rows"` even though I have `dplyr` installed.

Comment: It is from `dplyr_0.4.0` as the `rbind_list` is sort of deprecated.  So, try with `rbind_list(data_list)`

Comment: Getting this message now `rbind_list (data_list)
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows`

Comment: You can just use `do.call(rbind, data_list)`, no need for dplyr.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Ista! That did the trick. Now, how do I get this into a csv file. I tried the same command as above `write.csv (data_list, ("file.csv"), row.names = FALSE` and I'm getting the same error message `Error in data.frame(list(V1 = c(0.025, 0.035, 0.045, 0.055, 0.065, 0.075,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 500, 599, 508, 489, 547, 624, 587, 534, 499, 494, 566, 520, 541, 543, 615`

Comment: As I mentioned above, you are using `write.csv` on the list.

Comment: I did not know that was not allowed. What then are alternatives?

Comment: You could try `datNew <- do.call(rbind,data_list); write.csv(datNew, .....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is different options of achieving it.

R Code:

```
# Option 1: Using plyr
library(plyr)
datafiles <-list.files (pattern='*.txt') 
dataset <- ldply(datafiles, read.table, header=F)

# Option 2: Using fread
library(data.table)
datafiles <-list.files (pattern='*.txt') 
dataset = rbindlist(lapply( datafiles, fread, header=F))

# Option 3: do.call method
dataset <- do.call("rbind",lapply(datafiles,
                              FUN=function(files){read.table(files,
                                                             header=FALSE)}))

# Option 4: Loops are any time slow so avoid, but have put here just for reference
for (file in datafiles){  
  # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
  if (!exists("dataset")){
    dataset <- read.table(file, header=FALSE)
  }

  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
  if (exists("dataset")){
    temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=FALSE)
    dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }  
}

# Writing to csv
write.csv (dataset, ("file.csv"), row.names = FALSE, na="")
```

Comment: No need for the `header` arg in any of those. In `read.table` it defaults to `FALSE`. And no need for an anonymous function in `lapply()`.  You can do `do.call(rbind, lapply(datafiles, read.table))`

Answer (score 1):

I think using dplyr or plyr package functions is really overkill. Suggest trying write.table, (since there are no commas in the desired output):

```
write.table(file_A, file="comb_file.txt")
write.table(file_B, file="comb_file.txt", append=TRUE)
```

You certainly could use `write.csv` but then the output would not look like what you illustrated.